# FoxPro convert currency to numeric

Tags: visual-foxpro, replaceall

I'm using Visual FoxPro and I need to convert currency amount into numeric.  The 2 columns in the table are tranamt(numeric,12,2) and tranamt2(character)

Here's my example:

tranamt2=-$710,000.99

I've tried

`replace all tranamt with val(tranamt2)`

and

`replace all tranamt with val(strtran(tranamt2, ",",""))`

both results give me zero.  I know it has something to do with the negative sign but I can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
replace all tranamt with VAL(STRTRAN(STRTRAN(tranamt2, "$", ""), ",", ""))
```

This removes the dollar sign and comma in one shot.

Comment: I had to add the val() to the front but it worked, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I missed that and edited it, but apparently it wasn't approved in time. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

> need to convert currency amount into numeric
>   tranamt(numeric,12,2) and tranamt2(character)

First of all a neither a **Character** Field Type nor a **Numeric** Field type (tranamt2) are Not a VFP **Currency** Field type
You may be using the value of a Character field to represent currency, but that does not make it a currency value - just a String value.
And typically when that is done, you do NOT store the Dollar Sign '$' and Comma ',' as part of the data.
Instead, you store the 'raw' value (in this case: "-710000.99") and merely format how that 'raw' value is displayed when needed.

So in your Character field you have a value of:  -$710,000.99
Do you have the Dollar Sign '$' and the Comma ',' as part of the field data?
If so, to convert it to a Numeric, you will first have to eliminate those extraneous characters prior to the the conversion.
If they are not stored as part of your field value, then you can use the VAL() 'as is'.

Example:

```
cStr = "-710000.99"  && The '$' and ',' are NOT stored as part of Character value
nStr = VAL(cStr)
?nStr
```

However if you have the Dollar Sign and the Comma as part of the field data itself, then you can use STRTRAN() to eliminate them during the conversion.

Example:

```
cStr = "-$710,000.99"  && Note both '$' and ',' are part of data value
* --- Remove both '$' and ',' and convert with VAL() ---
nStr = VAL(STRTRAN(STRTRAN(cStr,",",""),"$",""))  
?nStr
```

Maybe something like:

```
REPLACE tranamt WITH VAL(STRTRAN(STRTRAN(tranamt2,",",""),"$",""))
```

EDIT: Another alternative would be to use  **CHRTRAN()** to remove the '$' and ','
Something like:

```
cRemoveChar = "$,"   && Characters to be removed from String
REPLACE tranamt WITH VAL(CHRTRAN(tranamt2,cRemoveChar,""))
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I use this function call

```
function MoneyToDecimal
    LPARAMETER tnAmount
    LOCAL lnAmount
    IF VARTYPE(tnAmount) = "Y"
        lnAmount = VAL(STRTRAN(TRANSFORM(tnAmount), "$", ""))
    ELSE
        lnAmount = tnAmount
    ENDIF
    return lnAmount
endfunc
```

And can be tested with these calls:

```
wait wind MoneyToDecimal($112.50)
wait wind MoneyToDecimal($-112.50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in MTON() function to convert a currency value into a numeric value:

```
replace all tranamt with mton(tranamt2)
```